# Removing properties and elements set to null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a review of the following code.

1. Is there a better way to remove all properties that evaluate to truthy for a given function?
2. Is there a better way to prevent a stack overflow in the recursive function?

This is the entire Node.js module:

```
// The removePropertiesWhereTruthy function accepts the following parameters:
// 
// 1. an object or array
// 2. a function to call against each non-object or non-array to determine if it's a truthy value according to that function (e.g. _.isNull)
// 3. An optional maxRecursion value to prevent a stack-overflow when there's a circular reference or exceptionally deeply nested objects.
// 
'use strict';

var _  = require('lodash');

function removePropertiesWhereTruthy(obj,func,maxRecursion) {

  maxRecursion = _.isNumber(maxRecursion) ? maxRecursion - 1 : 20;
  if(maxRecursion < 0) {
    // prevent stack overflow by allowing caller to set a max time for
    // recursion and default to 20 if not set.
    return;
  }
  if(_.isObject(obj) && !_.isArray(obj)) {
    _.forOwn(obj, function(v, k) {
      if(_.isObject(v)) { // also true for array
        return removePropertiesWhereTruthy(v,func,maxRecursion);
      } else if(func(v)) {
        delete obj[k];
      }
    });
  } else if(_.isArray(obj)) {
    _.remove(obj, function(item){
      return func(item);
    });
    _.each(obj, function(v){
      if(_.isObject(v)) { // also true for (nested) array
        return removePropertiesWhereTruthy(v,func,maxRecursion);
      }
    });
  } else {
    throw new Error('This function should only be called with objects and arrays');
  }
}

function removePropertiesWithNullValues(obj, maxRecursion) {
  return removePropertiesWhereTruthy(obj, _.isNull, maxRecursion);
}

module.exports = {
  removePropertiesWithNullValues: removePropertiesWithNullValues
};
```

Comment: Could you explain what the code does in a bit more detail? What kind of input it accepts? What does it return?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - I added a comment about the parameters. The code removes any property with a value that evaluates to truthy based on the func parameter. It does not return anything as it manipulates the object and its properties in place.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any good use-case for this method. It may help to describe some examples of why you need this functionality.

That said, a few issues I see:

1. `func` could be named better (`predicate` perhaps?).
2. `maxRecursion` seems a bit unstable. This is where I have a hard time seeing the purpose of this method. What happens if you hit level 20 and it hasn't fully run it's course? Now you've got an object that is in a half-complete state without any way to know it. What if it spends 20 cycles on the first property which happens to be a circular reference?
3. I think the use of lodash here adds confusion to what would otherwise be pretty straightforward javascript (opinion).

Some fixes:

1. Don't use a recursive function. You could use a stack or a queue here to traverse the object tree.
2. Rather than limit the depth to avoid stack overflows for circular references, you could try to detect them by keeping a table of references and avoid re-traversing those trees altogether.
3. Rather than modifying an existing object, you could create a new one. That way, this method wouldn't produce any side-effects and potentially leave you in an unstable state. At minimum, you could return true/false if the method succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I like all your fixes. I was look at fix #3 and was wondering if I could achieve all this functionality through lodash's cloneDeep?
  
var clone = _.cloneDeep(view, function(value) {  
   return _.isElement(value) ? value.cloneNode(true) : undefined;  
 });  
  
I was wondering if the function passed into _.cloneDeep could somehow act as the predicate to achieve the copy without null values for example.

Comment: The documentation isn't super clear on how the callback in cloneDeep is used, but it would appear that it would do exactly what you need. You could just replace the `_.isElement(value)` line with `yourPredicate(value)`.